# How to get all fields for only a specic user_id from a pivot dataframe indexed by two fields 'timestamps' and 'user_id'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below contained in the DataFrame pivoted below :

```
        cost        cost        cost        val1        val1        val1    
user_id     1       2       3       1       2       3   
timestamp
01/01/2011      1               100     3               5   
01/02/2011              20  8           
01/07/2012      19  57                  
01/11/2012  3100    49  
21/12/2012              240 30          
14/09/2013      21  63                  
01/12/2013  3200    51
```

I would like to know how I obtain another dataframe containing only fields associated to a specific user-id, i.e (based on my example) to be able to obtain something like df_by_user_id = pivoted ['user_id'=1] or df_by_user_id = pivoted ['user_id'=2] or df_by_user_id = pivoted ['user_id'=3] (knowing that the table above is grouped by 'timestamp' and 'user_id). (My final purpose being to be able to make a plot for each user_id).

The code use in order to obtain the above table is :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['timestamp','user_id', 'cost', 'val1','val2', 'val3','code']
df = pd.read_csv('mytest.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True) 
pivoted = df.pivot('timestamp', 'user_id')
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: just a comment on the formatting of your question: use `print(df.to_string())` to get a legible text version of the dataframe.

Comment: the code you posted to generate your table isn't useful since no one but you has `mytest.csv'`

Answer (score 1):

So let's start out with this reproducible dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
np.random.seed(0)

N = 6
data = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=200, size=(N, N))
cols = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([('cost', 'value'), (1, 2, 3)], names=['quantity', 'user_id'])
dates = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='1M', start='2010-01-01', periods=N, name='date')
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=cols, index=dates)
```

which is:

```
quantity    cost            value          
user_id        1    2    3      1    2    3
date                                       
2010-01-31   172   47  117    192   67  195
2010-02-28   103    9   21     36   87   70
2010-03-31    88  140   58    193   39   87
2010-04-30   174   88   81    165   25   77
2010-05-31    72    9  148    115  197   79
2010-06-30   175  192   82     99  177   29
```

Take a cross-section (`xs`) along axis 1 of the dataframe

```
df.xs(1, level='user_id', axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
quantity    cost  value
date                   
2010-01-31   172    192
2010-02-28   103     36
2010-03-31    88    193
2010-04-30   174    165
2010-05-31    72    115
2010-06-30   175     99
```

Alternatively, you could pick out all of the costs with:

```
df.xs('cost', level='quantity', axis=1)

user_id       1    2    3
date                     
2010-01-31  172   47  117
2010-02-28  103    9   21
2010-03-31   88  140   58
2010-04-30  174   88   81
2010-05-31   72    9  148
2010-06-30  175  192   82
```

Since that level of the columns isn't named in your dataframe, you can access it with it's index:

```
df.xs('cost', level=0, axis=1)

user_id       1    2    3
date                     
2010-01-31  172   47  117
2010-02-28  103    9   21
2010-03-31   88  140   58
2010-04-30  174   88   81
2010-05-31   72    9  148
2010-06-30  175  192   82
```

If you had a multi-level index on rows, you could use `axis=0` to select items base on row labels. But since you're concerned with columns right now, use `axis=1`

Comment: If I have properly understood : I use this_user_id=1 and obtain a table with all associated values by pivoted.xs(this_user_id, level='user_id', axis=1). But I don't understand 'use axis=0 to select items base on row labels'. Can you please detailed this last part?

Comment: Ok. I found some explanation here : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html . Thanks.

Comment: if you had a multi-level index on the rows and wanted to take a cross-setion, you would use `axis=0`. but since you want a cross-section of columns, you use `axis=1`. see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html?highlight=xs#pandas.DataFrame.xs (all examples are on `axis=0`)

Comment: It still a bit confusing : How can I take for example all 'cost' fields for all users?

Comment: @user3102882 edited my response. post some useful code to generate a dataframe since you haven't posted the content of `mytest.csv`

Comment: When I have all cost, there is a way to make a sum of these columns (for each date)?

Comment: @user3102882 that's an entirely different question, one that is answered in may other places on SO and the pandas documentation and the rest of the web. That said, here's how you do it: `df.xs('cost', level=0, axis=1).sum(axis=1)`